# Restsharp response doesn't support Arabic characters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, restsharp

I'm using post man code generate c# into the my code, send any request in postman and get arabic character correctly but when that code copy into my c# project with this source code:

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "text/csv");
request.AddParameter("application/json;charset=UTF-8", "{\r\n    \"params\": {\r\n        \"auth_remoteaddr\": \"192.168.1.101\",\r\n        \"auth_type\": \"ADMIN\",\r\n        \"auth_name\": \"system\",\r\n        \"auth_session\": \"4crswevkjutd\",\r\n        \"normal_username\": \"10001084\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"method\": \"user.getUserInfo\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

get this response:

> "name": "\u0633\u0647\u0646\u062f \u0633\u0627\u0631\u06cc
> \u0627\u0635\u0644\u0627"

Can't get the Arabic characters but in postman show it correct. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Seems that `\u0633` [_is_ an Arabic character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0633/index.htm).

Comment: @UweKeim in post man show real arabic character for example ب but in c# restsharp not show

Comment: How can RestSharp "show" a character? After all, it is just a library for retrieving from REST APIs. Please also read "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: find my answer in this link: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086825/get-json-response-using-restsharp

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you write this sentence "Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
seem to be good everything just you should change this point in the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

After you receive the response use the below code to convert the response to object or class

`var res= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(response.Content);`

note: if you convert the content json to class you replace the object type by class name like this **DeserializeObject**
so **res** variable will be the data of the class.